# How do I retrieve aliased items and/or items in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table of items in  SQL Server 2008 which are setup as follows:

ITEMS TABLE

```
itemId (PK) | Ref 
1           | item1
2           | item2
```

I also have a table to store aliases of these items:

ALIASES TABLE

```
aliasId(PK) | objectId(FK) | AliasOfId(FK) | Ref 
10          | 50           | 1             | A1
20          | 51           | 2             | A2
30          | 52           | 2             | A3
```

I am trying to produce a query to so that I can retrieve a list of items but I'm having problem in that I can only seem to get either items OR aliases not both (problem I'm having is LEFT JOIN always joins to aliases.

SQL used is below. Any ideas, appreciate any help?

```
SELECT  
      ISNULL(A.objectId,I.itemId) AS itemId 
     ,ISNULL(A.ref,I.ref) AS ref
     ,isAlias = CASE WHEN A.aliasID IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END

FROM        items I
LEFT JOIN   aliases A ON (I.itemId = A.AliasOfId)
WHERE       
      ISNULL(A.objectId,I.itemId) = 1
   OR ISNULL(A.objectId,I.itemId) = 51
   OR ISNULL(A.ref,I.ref) = 'A3'
```

---

I had put data in with the question but it seems to have reformatted it. Here's the full data in SQL 2008.

```
CREATE TABLE [items]
( [itemId] [int] NOT NULL
, [ref] [varchar](50) NOT NULL )
 ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE TABLE [aliases]
( [aliasId] [int] NOT NULL
, [objectId] [int] NOT NULL
, [aliasOfId] [int] NOT NULL
, [ref] [varchar](50) NOT NULL )
 ON [PRIMARY]

 INSERT INTO [items] ([itemId],[ref])
 VALUES (1, 'Item1'),(2, 'Item2')

 INSERT INTO [aliases] ([aliasId],[objectId],[aliasOfId],[ref])
 VALUES
 (10, 50, 1, 'A1')
,(20, 51, 2, 'A2')
,(30, 52, 2, 'A3')
```

Comment: I would suggest that your design makes no sense and should be changes as it will never be easy or efficient to query. It makes so little sense I can't even figure out what you are trying to accomplish to suggest a better design. Suggest you first read about database normalization before trying to deisgn a better structure.

Comment: Thanks for your response, and I am fully aware of database normalisation. maybe I didn't make the situation clear enough.

I'm trying to achieve a quite common DB situation, the items table contains folders, and the aliases table gives new ids to elements that point to the folders (i.e. a shortcut to a folder).

Does that make it any clearer?

Comment: Try giving us some sample data

Comment: I had put data in with the question but it seems to have reformatted it. Here's the full data in SQL 2008.

CREATE TABLE [items](
 [itemId] [int] NOT NULL,
 [ref] [varchar](50) NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE TABLE [aliases](
 [aliasId] [int] NOT NULL,
 [objectId] [int] NOT NULL,
 [aliasOfId] [int] NOT NULL,
 [ref] [varchar](50) NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]


INSERT INTO [items] ([itemId],[ref])
VALUES  (1, 'Item1'),(2, 'Item2')

INSERT INTO [aliases] ([aliasId],[objectId],[aliasOfId],[ref])
VALUES (10, 50, 1, 'A1'),(20, 51, 2, 'A2'),(30, 52, 2, 'A3')

Answer (score 1):

```
    SELECT  
        Ref          AS item
        ItemId 
        Ref
        1            AS isAlias
    FROM 
        items i
UNION ALL
    SELECT  
        i.Ref        AS item
        a.objectID   AS itemId 
        a.Ref        AS ref
        0            AS isAlias
    FROM 
        items i
      JOIN
        aliases a
          ON i.itemId = a.AliasOfId
```

Comment: Why didn't I think of that!! Thanks so much.